# nginx: how to setup as caching reverse proxy for global URLs

Tags: nginx, caching, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am looking for a way to setup nginx to run as a reverse proxy(?) with caching but explicitly taking/rewriting original URLs, where the URL is no local server but any generic address.

E.g., I would like to explicitly cache/proxy URLs. So, for an original URL like **https://org.url.baz/user/repo/foo** I would like to be able to cache all request through nginx at **my.domain.foo** with a explicit "cache request" like

http://my.domain.foo/cache/http://org.url.baz/user/repo/foo

and rewrite all subsequent request. I.e., similar to Internet Archive's memento syntax **archive.org/save/org.url.baz**

Since my idea is no 'true' reverse proxy in any sense, the example in https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/ is not fully applicable but needs heavy extension, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking after something like [this](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/proxy-requests-to-any-remote-server-in-nginx).

Specifically:

```
location ~* ^/cache/(?<pschema>https?)/(?<phost>[\w.]+)(?<puri>/.*) {
{
    set $adr $pschema://$phost;
    rewrite .* $puri break;

    proxy_pass $adr;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $phost;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    expires 30;
}
```

This would proxy `your.example.com/cache/https/org.url.baz/user/repo/foo` to `https://org.url.baz/user/repo/foo`

Note that `your.example.com/cache/https://org.url.baz/user/repo/foo` would probably not be a valid URL, so your URLs should not include `://` in protocol specifier of remote websites.